# Future date not Properly Displayed from Koyami Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

[image]I am referd using following link

https://github.com/shoheiyokoyama/Koyomi#demo_app

I want to pick date (startDate to endDate) from calendar. if I am using Koyami Calendar pick the date from following method.

```
 func koyomi(_ koyomi: Koyomi, didSelect date: Date?, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You Selected: \(date!)")
 }
```

if I am using this function first  I select the start date Example(20.2.2018) and select the endDate Example(18.2.2018). Output will be displayed correctly. Because I select the previous date from startDate my console output is

```
You Selected: 2018-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
You Selected: 2018-02-18 18:30:00 +0000
```

if I am using same function first  I select the startDate Example(20.2.2018) and endDate Example(22.2.2018).Output will be displayed correctly.Because I select the future date from startDate my console output is

```
You Selected: 2018-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
You Selected: 2018-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
```

My problem is When I pick the future date for endDate, startDate and endDate Same date will be displyed. But i want to displyed properly my ecpectd output is

```
You Selected: 2018-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
You Selected: 2018-02-22 18:30:00 +0000
```

How can I fix the issue.Please help me!

Comment: Add some code to understand issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. I am using github project

Comment: I am adding github link sir

Comment: Explain you problem in steps. like 1. I pick the future date future date for endDate. 2. then future date for startDate. etc

Comment: when select the endDate.   start date and end date same date will be displayed

Comment: Now i am added screenshot sir

Comment: from the screen shot i am picking startDate(20.02.2018) and end date is (28.02.2018) . but display the output in console ( startDate and endDate) sameDate(The SameDate is StartDate) will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through documentation of koyomi. By default its in `sequence` mode for multiple selection use `multiple` mode. It will give you 2 different date on selection.

```
    koyomi.selectionMode = .multiple(style: .background) //.sequence(style: .semicircleEdge)
```

**Update** : Use same selection mode =  `.sequence(style: .semicircleEdge)` and get start and end date from method :
In this start date will be `date` and end date is `toDate`

```
func koyomi(_ koyomi: Koyomi, shouldSelectDates date: Date?, to toDate: Date?, withPeriodLength length: Int) -> Bool {
    print("Start date \(date)")
    print("End date : \(toDate)")

    if length > invalidPeriodLength {
        print("More than \(invalidPeriodLength) days are invalid period.")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: selection mode is not problem. problem is didSelect method for date.

Comment: didSelect method date display not properly sir

Comment: In didSelect method StartDate and End Date same Date displyed. just printed the console

Comment: You want 2 dates. right (Start date -first click and end date )

Comment: @VigneshJeyaraj check out update answer. Use `shouldSelectDates` to get both dates.